# Get end value of multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've got an multidimensional array of undefined length that looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 75
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 90
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 95
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [price] => 130
        )

)
```

How can I get the value of price of the last element in the array?

Cheers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this : `$array` is your input array

```
$arr   = end($array);
echo $arr['price'];
```

EDIT : And with PHP 5.4 or newer: `end($array)['price']` – fab **(Comment by fab)**

Comment: @fab : Yup exactly..I tried that in my local machine first as it is 5.3 it didnt worked :)

Answer (score 3):

just use this code `$arr` is your array.

```
echo $arr[count($arr) - 1]['price'];
```

Comment: Note that this only works with "plain" arrays (i.e. contiguously numbered, starting from 0).